# ssh login using expect to directly login using c

Tags: c, ssh, expect

I have created a c program using expect to login a server using ssh, the following is the program

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <tcl8.6/expect.h>
int main()
{
exp_is_debugging = 0;
exp_timeout = 60;


FILE *expect = exp_popen((char *) "ssh user@ip");
if (expect == 0) {
    return 1;
}

enum { denied, invalid, command_not_found, 
        command_failed, prompt };

switch (exp_fexpectl(expect,
            exp_glob, "password: ", prompt,
            exp_end)) {
    case prompt:
            // continue 
            break;
    case EXP_TIMEOUT:
            return 1;
}

   fprintf(expect, "%s\r","password");

 switch (exp_fexpectl(expect,
            exp_glob, "denied", denied, // 1 case       
            exp_glob, "invalid password", invalid, // another case
            exp_glob, "#", prompt, // third case           
            exp_end)) {
    case denied:
    printf("denied %d",exp_glob); 
             break;
    case invalid:
            break;
    case EXP_TIMEOUT:
    printf("EXP_TIMEOUT"); 
            break;
    case prompt:
            printf("loggedin");        
            break;
    default:
    //return 0;
            break;
}
}
```

I am able to login to the server but it immediately gone to my terminal after this, what i am looking to login to the server and need to interact with that terminal. Now, it is showing my terminal after that, do anyone have any idea on this ? i need to stay on that logged server's terminal

Comment: Don't post [the same](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47260811/2371524) ...
 [questions again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47257485/2371524). Instead, clarify and improve your previous ones.

Comment: And apart from that, try [libssh2](https://www.libssh2.org/) ... it doesn't make much sense to go to great lengths and automate the usage of an *interactive* tool.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any loop in your program. You just expect some output from your child process (ssh), reply accordingly, and finally terminate. When you terminate, your child process terminates as well. You'd have to indefinitely forward I/O between your `stdin`/`stdout` and the child process to achieve what you want.

That said, this whole idea is flawed. You just want to launch `ssh` and have the login done automatically, but use the shell interactively? There's no need to write code for that, have a look at `ssh-agent` and how to create an ssh key.

Comment: Hi Felix, Thank you for your reply, i am looking for that forward I/O between stdin/stdout, I read about exp_interactive in http://npg.dl.ac.uk/MIDAS/manual/ActiveTcl8.4.9.0-html/expect/libexpect.3.html#sect12 but couldn't see any proper example for it.

Comment: Hi Felix, In linux, we can use interact with expect to achieve this, is there any method like so in c ?

Comment: Are you trolling? :o Just to be absolutely clear, *whatever* you ultimately want to achieve (you could clarify that), the tool in your hand right now is **the wrong one**.

Comment: Hi Felix, Sorry, i don't meant that, actually, i am trying to create a c script to login in to a server directly. I already had done using expect using shell script 
set SER [lindex $argv 0]
set SSHU  [lindex $argv 1]
set SSHP [lindex $argv 2]
set PORT [lindex $argv 3]

spawn  ssh -l $SSHU $SER -p $PORT
expect "password:" { send "$SSHP\r" } \
       "yes" {
                send "yes\r"
                expect "assword:"
                send "$SSHP\r"
        }
expect "#" { interact } ">>" { interact }  and trying to do the same using expect in c

Comment: @DevelopersStaff and again this is the wrong tool. For automated login, use [SSH keys](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server), either without passphrase or better with an *ssh agent* running, and then a simple script will do.

Comment: @DevelopersStaff and if you ever need to connect to an SSH server from C code for some other reason, automating the *interactive* `ssh` command is *the wrong idea* as well, use [libssh2](https://www.libssh2.org/) for that.

Comment: Hi Felix, Thank you, what i am looking is in c is because i already have script and need to parse and pass some values from this script.

Comment: @DevelopersStaff still it's **very** likely you can achieve what you're after using SSH keys and a script in a simple **and secure** way.